# Can't write List<object> in Parcel

Tags: java, android

I'm created a model implements Parcelable.

```
public class ParcelableTreeNode implements Parcelable {
private TreeNode treeNode;
public ParcelableTreeNode(TreeNode treeNode){
    this.treeNode=treeNode;
}

public TreeNode getTreeNode(){
    return treeNode;
}

public int describeContents(){
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flag){

    out.writeList(treeNode.getmAncester());
    out.writeString(treeNode.getContent());
    out.writeInt(treeNode.getId());
    out.writeInt(treeNode.getLevel());
    out.writeString(treeNode.getParentId());
    out.writeList(treeNode.getChildren());

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableTreeNode> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableTreeNode>(){
    public ParcelableTreeNode createFromParcel(Parcel in){
        return new ParcelableTreeNode(in);
    }

    public ParcelableTreeNode[] newArray(int size){
        return new ParcelableTreeNode[size];
    }
};

private ParcelableTreeNode(Parcel in){
    List ancestor= new ArrayList<String>();
    List<TreeNode> children= new ArrayList<TreeNode>();

    in.readList(ancestor,null);
    String content= in.readString();
    int id=in.readInt();
    int level=in.readInt();
    String parentId=in.readString();
    in.readList(children,null);

    treeNode= new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(R.string.ic_drive_file,content));

    treeNode.setmAncester(ancestor);
    treeNode.setContent(content);
    treeNode.setChildren(children);
    treeNode.setId(id);
    treeNode.setParentId(parentId);

}
```

}

I want to pass list object TreeNode to another Activity(Fragment). But I have a problem when write a list child of object TreeNode to Parcel:

```
out.writeList(treeNode.getChildren());
```

***Logcat show: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value***

Write list of String to Parcel, it's ok. But list of object, that's problem occur.I take all one day to search and solve that problem but have nothing. Could anyone tell me what I must do?

Comment: is TreeNode parcelable as well?

Comment: I want to pass list object TreeNode with some attributes, it's ok if node haven't child

Comment: what does `getChildren` return? a `List` of non-`Parcelable` TreeNodes?

Comment: return List<TreeNode> of non- Parcelable TreeNodes

Comment: then carefully read `Parcel#writeList` documentation

Answer (score 1):

If you have a List in a "parcelable class", the elements of the list must be parcelables too.

In the ParcelableTreeNode(Parcel in) method, you have

```
(...) List<TreeNode> children= new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
(...) in.readList(children,null);
```

but TreeNode is no parcelable and that's the problem.

I don't know why are you using TreeNode and ParcelableTreeNode classes instead of only ParcelableTreeNode class, but if you put the attributes of TreeNode class into ParcelableTreeNode class, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, TreeNode is no parcelable and that's the problem .So, I using only TreeNode with parcelable to solve that

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem some days ago.

You could use `out.writeValue(treeNode.getChildren())` and in your contructor use `yourList = (List<?>) in.readValue(List.class.getClassLoader())`.

You'd have to exchange List for the appropriate return type of `treeNode.getChildren()`.